# reshape dataframe in pandas to layout data horizontally

Tags: python, pandas, reshape

I have the following DataFrame:

```
data = [['label1', 1234], ['label1', 12345], ['label2', 2345], ['label2', 4567], ['label3', 123], ['label2', 4589]]
pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['label', 'id'])
```

outputs:

```
    label   id
0   label1  1234
1   label1  12345
2   label2  2345
3   label2  4567
4   label3  123
5   label2  4589
```

I would like to reshape the data to the following:

```
    label   id1    id2    id3
0   label1  1234   12345  None
1   label2  2345   4567   4589
2   label3  123    None   None
```

Basically lay out the ids horizontally, and add unique labels to the ids, with each row keyed on label.

I was looking at pivoting operations in pandas, and I can't seem to figure out the exact incantation I need to get the data in the format I need for output.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign a new column to enumerate the ids, then use pivot:

```
(df.assign(ids='id' + (df.groupby('label').cumcount()+1).astype(str))
   .pivot(index='label', columns='ids', values='id'))
Out:
ids        id1      id2     id3
label                          
label1  1234.0  12345.0     NaN
label2  2345.0   4567.0  4589.0
label3   123.0      NaN     NaN
```